# How to change plot unit or scale the number of axis?

Tags: plotting

[image: Plot]

I want to use ms instead of s as the unit of x-axis. But frameticks seems not to work here as it cannot change the value of x-axis.

How to replace the number of x-axis 0.0001 with 1 or 0.1? Or just scale the x-axis?

Comment: Both of the answers below is working. Could I click accept to them both? Thank you guys.

Comment: However, I noticed that if we add "Frame -> True" in the program, they cannot work again. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you are asking.

Before

```
Plot[Sin[200 Pi t], {t, 0., .01}]
```

[image: before]

After

```
Plot[Sin[200 Pi t], {t, 0., .01},
  Ticks -> {{#, 1000 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., .01}, 5] // N, Automatic}]
```

[image: after]

#### Update

This update is in response to the comment made by drabus.

It's annoying but frame ticks must be specified somewhat differently from axis ticks. So if you are framing the plot, do it this way:

```
Plot[Sin[200 Pi t], {t, 0., .01},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks ->
    {Automatic, {{#, 1000 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., .01}, 5] // N, Automatic}}]
```

framed[image]

Comment: However, I noticed that if we add "Frame -> True" in the program, they cannot work again. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Thanks very much. It is solved.

Comment: If you add a frame, then you need to control ticks with the `FrameTicks` option and drop the `Ticks` option.

Comment: I noticed the ticks below x-axis are intergers but with a dot behind may lead mistake to readers. Can anybody remove the dots?

Comment: @ChadMeng. Remove the `// N`

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg Any ideas why this method isn't working for the FrameTicks environment? My code is FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}}, where ticks is defined as you mentioned. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @drabus. See my update to this answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for your effort, but it does't seem to work. I am using Mathematica 9.0 and [this](https://imgur.com/Nz5HsKC) is what I get after using your very same code.

Comment: @m_goldberg I got it right. It has to be like this:
`Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
   None}, {{#, 1000 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., .01}, 5] // N, None}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, .0001, .0005},
 Ticks -> {Table[{i, ToString[10000 i]}, {i, .0001, .0005, .0001}], 
   Automatic}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for you, too. Your answer help me a lot when I just want the frameticks downside the frame instead of ticks appear on both upside and downside.

Comment: I noticed the ticks below x-axis are intergers but with a dot behind may lead mistakes to readers. Do you know how to remove the dots?

Comment: @Chad Meng  Sure:  `Ticks -> {Table[{i, Round[10000 i]}, {i, .0001, .0005, .0001}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot with your kindness.